# Does Passport utilize guards not to authenticate users but to validate access tokens on routes where these tokens are required?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-7, laravel-passport, laravel-authentication

I'm a little bit confused by [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#protecting-routes). It's said:

> Passport includes an authentication guard that will **validate access**
> **tokens** on incoming requests. Once you have configured the api guard to
> use the passport driver, you only need to specify the auth:api
> middleware on **any routes that require a valid access token**.

So it means that Passport utilizes guards not to authenticate users but to validate access tokens on routes where these tokens are required. Did I get that right?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, validating the access token **is** authenticating the user. To understand why this is the case, let's walk through a simplified authentication flow using JWTs (let's ignore oAuth2 for a bit).

1. The user is logging in on the website. This triggers a `POST /login` request, with the `username` and the `password` in the request body.
2. The backend validates the users credentials. If the credentials are valid, it will issue a JWT, which will act as an access token. The JWT payload will contain some data that allows the backend to identify a user, e. g. the user id. The JWT then is signed with a secret that only the backend knows.
3. The backend will return the access token to the client, who has to include the access token in any subsequent requests to the server. Usually, the client will provide the token in the `Authorization` header.
4. When handling the next request from the client, the backend will extract the access token from the `Authorization` header and check its signature. If the signature is valid, the backend can be sure that the token data has not been manipulated, e. g. by changing the user id on the access token. With a valid signature, the backend can extract the user id from the tokens payload and set the `User` model for that specific id as authenticated. With an invalid signature, the backend will probably return something like `401 Unauthorized`.